# Get rid of "Lost access to message queue" in a simple Python script

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

The little script below gives me "Lost access to message queue" when it ends.
I'm not very good at Python. So how do I get rid of it?

```bash
pi@raspberrypi:$ peder.py
25.0  41.0 
Temp: 77.0 F / 25.0 C    Humidity: 41% 
Lost access to message queue
```

Script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
import board
import time


import adafruit_dht


dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D17)

try:
        # Print the values to the serial port
        temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
        temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
        humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
        print("%-3.1f " % temperature_c + " " + "%-3.1f " % humidity)
        print(
            "Temp: {:.1f} F / {:.1f} C    Humidity: {}% ".format(
                temperature_f, temperature_c, humidity
            )
        )
       
except RuntimeError as error:
        # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
        print(error.args[0])
        time.sleep(2.0)

except Exception as error:
        dhtDevice.exit()
        raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has these lines at the end.

```
except Exception as error:
    dhtDevice.exit()
    raise error
```

This code will run if your script crashes within the `try` block. It turns off the dhtDevice. Assuming that your program does not crash, this code will not run, and your dhtDevice is never turned off. That seems to be what causes the "Lost access to message queue" message.

To solve it you should only have to add `dhtDevice.exit()` at the very end of your script. Make sure it's not indented, so it's not part of the `except` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with pulseio True/False:

```
dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT11(board.D17, use_pulseio=True)
```